# Linter shows two images for my page but only the first is offered when posting on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get my site to play nicely with Facebook posts.  I've run it through Facebook's linter and it shows two entries for og:image and shows me the actual images.

When I try to post this on Facebook it only shows the first image, not offering the second one as an option.  I'm using two links with rel="image_src" and two meta tags for the og:image property.

Page:
http://demo.hosted2.panopto.com/Panopto/Pages/Viewer.aspx?id=641286df-2125-48e5-a839-91d196beea46

Any idea what's going wrong here?